# can a header logo image overflow the 955px normal width of content?

Tags: html, css

Im a novice, apologies up front if this is unclear!  I know what I want, but Im not sure how to get there or if its even possible with HTML/CSS.  Ive been trying for a week with no luck.

The main content area is 955px wide.  In the header, I have a logo in the upper right corner of this 955px width, but would like the logo to continue to the right, for computers that have a higher res.  So the main header area is set to margin: 0 auto, and I can put a 1px wide sliver to repeat to the right which is ok, but I would prefer the image to continue, not just some boring gradient.

Is this possible?

I created this image to show what I mean but cant post it because i need 11 rep and have 10. ;)

In it, the logo has been split into Image 1 & 2, but of course, if its possible to overflow the centered 955px wide header, then it could be one image.

I can get it to work fine with two images, as long as the window width isnt altered - then you can see Image 2 moving and doesn't line up with Image 1.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer for you, but I'd expect a solution to emerge if you were to experiment with `DIV`s, and the `overflow`, `background-position` and `background-repeat` properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to both Tullo and COBOLdinosaur - I couldn't get your suggestions to work right (probably more to do with my lack of skills) but you guys helped me figure out the solution to my problem.  Here's what I did:

Created the image in one piece, rather than two images.  Floated right within a 955px wide main-header container div.  And then I used negative margins to push the image further to the right.  This seems to work great.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Put the image in a div with a width of 100% and with a background color that matches up nicely with the image.  Then for the CSS on the image remove the margin and include

clear:both; float:right;